# BroadcastReceiver as it's own class or instantiate it internally in an activity or service class? which is better?

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

Which is better?  To instantiate a Broadcast receiver inside an Activity or in Service class, or make a class that extends BroadcastReceiver?

Below is an example where I instantiate BroadcastReceiver inside a Service class.

```
  　public BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    private String filename;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
        String action = intent.getAction();
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        filename = extras.getString("AudioPath");
    Toast.makeText(AudioService.this, "the audio file name sent: " + filename , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if(action.equals("com.porno.xxx.AudioPlay")){
            selectedAudioPath = audiopath;
            String state = intent.getExtras().getString("stringdata");
            playSong();
            Toast.makeText(AudioService.this, "play audio from service string data "+ state, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        else if(action.equals("com.porno.xxx.AudioPause")){
            pauseSong();

            selectedAudioPath = audiopath;
            Toast.makeText(AudioService.this, "pause audio from service", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else if(action.equals("com.porno.xxx.AudioSelector")){
            Toast.makeText(AudioService.this, "music selector from service", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent i = new Intent();
            audiopath = intent.getStringExtra("filename");
            Toast.makeText(AudioService.this, "selelcted audio path: " + audiopath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else if(action.equals("com.porno.xxx.AudioRelease")){
            Toast.makeText(AudioService.this, "My Service Stopped and destoryed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            player.stop();
            if (player != null) player.release();

                }   

        }

};
```

Comment: may be [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7636273/what-is-the-best-way-of-create-broadcastreceiver) will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you plan what you want to do with broadcast receiver. Then you analyze the best and feasible solutions.
If you want to register and unregister the broadcast receiver inside the activity then your source code is ok.

For example if you want to invoke the broadcast receiver when the application is not executing.(which means come out of application and not force close). Then you should not register and unregister the broadcast receiver in coding.
For that you create/implement a seperate class extends from BroadcastReceiver.
In manifest file you want to add the broadcast receiver.

Answer (score 1):

*An answer was submitted and accepted while I was typing, so here's where I was at, glad you found your answer already! :)*

Based on your (apparent) use as a media player, I'd recommend implementing the player as a Service (that can continue to run in the background if the user navigates away) or as an Activity (if this functionality isn't desired or appropriate for your app..)

A typical implementation of a `BroadcastReceiver` is as a stand-alone component of the application, declared in the Manifest, which allows it to receive broadcasts even when the application has been killed; it would be started to receive the broadcast, and then stopped after processing it.

Instead it might be advantageous to create the `BroadcastReceiver` as an inner class, as you've done. This is great when you're only handling your own actions, as it is easy to start and stop the receiver.

In your `Service`'s `onCreate()` method you can create the action filter, then it can easily be enabled or disabled based on the state of your application:

```
/* service */

public static final ACTION_PAUSE = "com.example.action_pause";

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON); /* Android action example */
    filter.addAction(MyClass.ACTION_PAUSE); /* Custom action example*/
    registerReceiver(mIntentReceiver, filter);
}

private BroadcastReceiver mIntentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.v(TAG, "mIntentReceiver.onReceive() action:"+ intent.getAction() );
        handleCommand(intent);
    } // end onReceive
}; /* end BroadcastReceiver */
```